# GridBagLayout button.setVisible (true/false)

Tags: java, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Trying to build a really simple UI with GridBagLayout, but when using setVisible(false/true) on Easy/Medium/Hard buttons, as expected the whole thing explodes. How do I set the textfield to be on top of the Check button? I did read the doc but having hard time grasping the logic behind all the GridBagLayout variables.

Left picture: Normal state 
Right picture: When one of the buttons (easy/medium/hard) has been clicked

[image: Current]
[image: After pressing a button]

Code:

```
GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    setLayout(gridbag);

    c.weightx = 4;
    c.weighty = 4;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0; 
    c.gridy = 6;
    JButton check = buttonFactory("Check", gridbag, c);
    c.gridx = 1; 
    c.gridy = 6;
    JButton easy = buttonFactory("Easy", gridbag, c);
    c.gridx = 2; 
    c.gridy = 6;
    JButton medium = buttonFactory("Medium", gridbag, c);
    c.gridx = 3; 
    c.gridy = 6;
    JButton hard = buttonFactory("Hard", gridbag, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 4;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    JLabel question = labelFactory(gridbag, c);

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.ipady = 30;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    JSeparator separator = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
    gridbag.setConstraints(separator, c);
    add(separator);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    JLabel answer = labelFactory(gridbag, c);

    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 6;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    JTextField userInput = new JTextField();
    gridbag.setConstraints(userInput, c);
    add(userInput);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand your layout. It seems like you are trying to replace 3 buttons with a single button. If so, then use a different layout.

The `Card Layout` was designed to allow you to swap panels containing different components. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information.

The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use GridBag Layout`, which will explain the constraints in more detail.

Comment: Yes, essentially thats what im trying to do. So you are saying that I should make 2 views (1 with Easy/Medium/Hard, and 1 with Check), and switch between these views accordingly using Card Layout?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting.